# Issues with calculating normals of a triangle

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl

I'm rendering some basic triangles, and I'm generating the normals in code. This is my "calculate normals" method. It gets the face normal of a triangle from its three vertices:

```
public static Vector3f calculateNormal(Vector3f v0, Vector3f v1, Vector3f v2) {
    Vector3f u = Vector3f.sub(v2, v0, null);
    Vector3f w = Vector3f.sub(v1, v0, null);

    Vector3f n = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f.cross(u, w, n);
    n.normalise(n);

    if (Float.isNaN(n.x) || Float.isNaN(n.y) || Float.isNaN(n.z)) {
        System.out.println("It's NaN!");
        return new Vector3f(0,1,0);
    }

    return n;
}
```

Except it outputs "NaN" for about half the triangles. I tried switching the order of the vertices, and that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sooo... did you do some basic debugging? Log what the triangle coordinates are when you see NaN: what can you say about the vectors you are computing the cross product for? What should the crossproduct be in those cases? To understand a problem, find out what input reliably reproduces it, and then analyse what that input does at each step. You don't stackoverflow just yet, the power to solve this problem is still entirely yours at this point in the problem solving process.

Comment: Can you give us one example of the vertices of a triangle for which this incorrectly shows `NaN`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `calculateNormal` function looks okay to me :)

But, the triangles with NaN normals, probably have *co-linear vertices* (i.e., they are degenerated triangles). Try checking if `n.length` is zero (or almost zero) to detect this edge case.

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing which math library you are using, I cannot answer specifically.  However, to find the cross product with 3 points, you need to find the vector from one point to the other two.

```
Vector3f toPoint2 = point2 - point1;
Vector3f toPoint3 = point3 - point1;
```

Once you have the two vectors, you need to find their cross product, which is orthogonal to both `toPoint2` and `toPoint3`.  In order to find the cross product, find the determinate of the following matrix:

```
[i          j          k         ]
[toPoint2.x toPoint2.y toPoint2.z]
[toPoint3.x toPoint3.y toPoint3.z]
```

The cross product is:

`Vector3f vec = new Vector3f(toPoint2.y * toPoint3.z - toPoint2.z * toPoint3.y, 
                             toPoint2.z * toPoint3.x - toPoint2.x * toPoint3.z,
                             toPoint2.x * toPoint3.y - toPoint2.y * toPoint3.x)`

This cross product will result in the normal vector of `point1` with respect to `point2` and `point3`.

Comment: OP is using LWJGL.  They have put a tag on the question to say so.  It has a method for calculating a cross product, so they don't need to write it themselves.

Comment: OP did not designate LWJGL 2 or LWJGL 3, so I didn't know lwjgl_utils or JOML

Comment: OK.  But either way, it seems to me that you're telling OP to do all the things they're already doing.